# How do downgrade kernel on Zesty (17.04) to Yakkety (16.10)

Tags: kernel, downgrade

After upgrading from 16.10 to 17.04 I hit various bugs and I need to downgrade my kernel to the previous one 4.10 -> 4.8

How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest doing a fresh install of 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Is your old kernel still installed? If so, simply select it at GRUB. That's why you keep one or two older kernels.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add yakkety sources as if it were a ppa. For that

   `$ sudo bash -c "cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep zesty | sed 's/zesty/yakkety/g' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yakkety.list"`
2. Update your apt cache

   `$ sudo apt update`
3. Install last yakkety kernel

   `$ sudo apt install linux-image-4.8.0-52-generic linux-headers-4.8.0-52-generic`

After that, in grub, you'll have to select this kernel in every boot sequence.